# Test flutter website on an iPhone Simulator but as a website and not an app

Tags: flutter, dart, ios-simulator, flutter-web

I have programmed a website and now I want to test it on an iPhone simulator but as a website and not an application. When I try to run it on the iPhone simulator it tries to open my algorithm with an app. Is there a solution?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested in dimensions of your app, select browser as a simulator (Chrome). Then select your device on developer tab. Here is [link](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/device-mode/) to tell you how to configure it.

Answer (score 3):

This is possible.

1. Run your app as a web server:

`flutter run -d web-server --web-port 8080 --web-hostname 0.0.0.0`

2. Launch the simulator, open Safari, type `http://your-laptop-ip-address:8080` and you're good to go.